# How do I remove the imported Segments in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I used 'import from gallery' to import some segments but later I find it not useful. But I can't just remove them.

[image]

There is a 'remove' choice in the 'Actions' pop-menu but it's not working. No matter how many times I tried, they are not removed.

Thanks,